# The right hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code in JS and I need to make it work in TypeScript.
It keeps saying:

> The right hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

```
sort(field, reverse, primer) {  
    var key = primer ? 
    function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : 
    function(x) {return x[field]};

    reverse = [-1, 1][+!!reverse];

    return function (a, b) {
        return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b)) - (b > a));
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `reverse * ((a > b))` this is number * boolean.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes but `-` will convert back to numeric. In any case the OP has Typescript code, not JavaScript code.

Comment: @Pointy, yes, and that's exactly what the error message is about, it's a compile time error because he is using an arithmetic operation where the inferred type of one operand is boolean.

Comment: convert any booleans to numbers before applying any arithmetics

Comment: @ASDFGerte ah right, good point :) I'm not a Typescript user so I don't have much a feel for what it complains about I guess.

Comment: Just as an additional note: There is a bracket missing: In `return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b)) - (b > a));`, the last bracket doesn't fit. Did you maybe not intend to enclose this in double brackets, which already causes readability issues for no reason: `((a > b))`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey how do I do that in this case?

Comment: `+(a > b) - (b > a)` maybe, or just `a - b`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The Problem

`(a > b)` and `(b > a)` both return `boolean` and additionally `((a > b))` has a bracket too much.

To resolve this, both `boolean` results have to be converted to `number`.
This can be achieved by one of these 3 methods:

```
1. +bool
2. bool ? 1 : 0
3. Number(bool)
```

#### The Solution (using Method #1):

```
sort(field, reverse, primer) {  
    var key = primer ? 
    function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : 
    function(x) {return x[field]};

    reverse = [-1, 1][+!!reverse];

    return function (a, b) {
        return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * (+(a > b) - +(b > a));
    } 
}
```

Note:

Using `(+(a > b) - (b > a))` would not work, since the `-` will not work as an arithmetic conversion but a subtraction, therefore keeping the type error.

Comment: Oh wow! It was as simple as putting Number(<number to convert>)

Answer (score 7):

I got to this error because I was using Typescript and marked a variable as `Number` instead of `number`.

Woops! Typescript docs do mention not to use `Number`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean

I opened an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45460

Answer (score 0):

```
insights = [
    {
        "title": "The Transportation KPIs You Should Be Tracking",
        "publishedDate": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "title": "Morey's Piers and Water Parks Makes a Splash with Aptean TabWare EAM",
        "publishedDate": "2022-06-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    }]

insights = insights.sort((a: Insight, b: Insight) =>
          a.publishedDate > b.publishedDate ? -1 : 1
        );
console.log(insights);
```

Use boolean as true or false